# multiprocessing and ProcessPoolExecutor doesn't do anything

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've just started to try out multiprocessing and something just doesn't work. I tired to run the simplest things possible and they just won't do.

I tried to run this in IDLE Shell 3.10.4 on Windows 10:

```
import multiprocessing

def blah(string = "Hello World!"):
  print(string)

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=blah)
p.start()
print('started p')
p.join()
print('joined p')
```

and got

```
started p
joined p
```

I tried to replicate an example from [here](https://analyticsindiamag.com/run-python-code-in-parallel-using-multiprocessing/#:%7E:text=Multiprocessing%20in%20Python%20enables%20the,run%20tasks%2Fprocesses%20in%20parallel.&text=Multiprocessing%20enables%20the%20computer%20to,involve%20a%20lot%20of%20computation.):

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

start = time.perf_counter()
def useless_function(sec = 1):
  print(f'Sleeping for {sec} second(s)')
  time.sleep(sec)
  print(f'Done sleeping')
  return sec

secs = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
  pool = [executor.submit(useless_function, i) for i in secs]
  for i in concurrent.futures.as_completed(pool):
    print(f'Return Value: {i.result()}')

end = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Finished in {round(end-start, 2)} second(s)')
```

and run that in the Shell. It's not doing anything. It gets stuck in the process as if it would be loading. CPU goes from 14% to 29% and stays there. Even trying to interrupt execution won't get it out o that state. If I close Shell, it asks if I want to kill the process.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Protect all the lines from `p = multiprocessing.Process(target=blah)` on with an `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: If that fixes things, see the "Safe importing of main module" subsection of [The spawn and forkserver start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) section of the multiprocessing [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) in the documentation.

Comment: run multiprocessing directly in console/terminal - IDLE may redirect `print` to its window but multiprocess runs separated process which may use original settings and print to original `stdout` and you can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `if __name__ == '__main__':` and the console as martineau and furas pointed out solved this.